# How to find Particle Position at Time with velocity and friction?

Tags: mathematics, particles

I have a Particle `p`.
A particle consists of a start position `p0`,an age `t`, a velocity `v` and a friction `f`

How can I find the position `pt` at an arbitrary `t`?

I currently have the formula

`pt = p0 + (v*t)`, which works fine.

But I don't know how to corporate `f` into it.

`f` is a multiplier, that should reduce velocity per timestep:
`v' = v*f`

I tried `p0 + (v*t * (f/t))` but at time 0 it's a division by 0, and when `t` is high, `pt` converges to `p0`

Comment: What platform is this for? Ones Like Unity and UnrealEngine already have inbuilt methods for things like this?

Comment: @akaBase neither

Comment: [This is more complicated than it might seem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185803/39518), and I'm not sure whether a closed-form solution exists.

Comment: @DMGregory I see. Thanks. Is there a rough approximation (it doesnt have to be mathematically accurate, it's for visual purposes only) I can use? All I want is slow down the particles according to some parameter and I would like to keep the loop for the particles as tight as possible, without any expensive calculations.

Comment: See the bottom of that answer I linked, where I suggest such an approximation for short time steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
pt = p0 + v*t - 0.5ft^2
```

It's the physical equation for motion with constant deceleration, just make sure to stop it and save the position when v reaches 0:

```
Vfinal = V - f*t
```

So for V final = 0 you wanna stop it at `t = v/f`