# Trouble using delta in my movement function

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

```
this.up = function () {
  this.velocity += this.lift * deltaTime;
};
this.update = function () {
  this.velocity += this.gravity * deltaTime;

  this.velocity *= 0.9;
  this.y += this.velocity;
}
```

Hi, I have a 2d game on canvas using p5 js thats basically like flappy bird . But Im trying to use deltaTime so the movement is the same regardless of fps.

Does anyone know how I'd apply deltaTime to keep the movement consistent across all fps?

I think it has something to do with the velocity being reduced by 0.9 but Im not sure how to apply delta to that part. Help would be appreciated

Comment: See also [Calculating framerate-independent values for linear, quadratic, and exponential functions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185803/39518).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a time step for constant continuous motion like this:

```
y += velocity * deltaTime
```

This only works where the motion is constant. That is, speed is not changing so distance is just how fast for how long.

When you have acceleration and changing speed, you need to use the [equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion). This will tell you how to calculate distance over time with changing velocity. You can imagine that if you are applying gravity to the velocity, then the speed at the start of the time step is different to the speed at the end of the time step, so assuming constant motion will lead to errors.

You might consider using the equations of motion to calculate both your velocity and position like this:

```
velocity = old_velocity + gravity * deltaTime [1]
deltaY = 0.5 * (velocity + old_velocity) * deltaTime [3]
```

This is not the only way to apply the equations.

If you do this, even though you are simulating in discrete time steps, the results will converge to actual Newtonian physics.

Comment: With that second part of code, where is the [1] and [3] coming from? Also would deltaY be the this.y in my code? Kinda confused

Comment: Sorry it was a bit confusing. [1] and [3] are the numbers for the equations I used, they are sometimes listed in order from 1 to 5. `deltaY` is the change in position, so in your code it would look like `this.y += deltaY`.

Comment: Ah okay, I tried using your equation but, should I still keep this.velocity *= 0.9 or does that need to be replaces by the line velocity = old_velocity etc.

Im having a hard time getting this to work unfortunately

Comment: Not sure what 0.9 represents in your system. If it's for drag, you should think about having acceleration in your system as `a = this.lift + this.gravity + 0.9 * this.velocity`. One way to set the velocity and position is `this.velocity += a * deltatTime` and  `this.y += this.velocity * deltaTime - 0.5 * a * deltaTime * deltatTime`.

Comment: So that last part you multiply by delta 3 times? Its weird too because when I use that acceleration it says the value of it is infinity, Im not sure

Comment: The value of `a` is infinity?

Comment: yes the value of a

Comment: My guess for `a` was based on assumptions on what `0.9` was doing in your code. I think this post answers the question of how to make smooth movement regardless of fps. I don't know why it's not working for you sorry.