# How to properly port 30 FPS physics with integers to 60 FPS and maybe floats?

Tags: physics, frame-rate

I've inherited a code base in which everything is coded to run at 30 FPS and uses integers.

I would like to upgrade the frame rate to 60 FPS, naturally I thought about using floats but it ain't that easy to do so. I created a git branch and tried to port what appeared to made sense to use float but it ended up catastrophic, things would fly everywhere on the screen, presumably because of rounding issues...

Then I considered why simply not keeping integers as that would be simpler but also not introduce subtle bugs that will be hard to track.

This is an example of how the code is, many things are updated against frame rate ratios:

```
playerShip.ThrustMagnitude += Timing.Instance.FR15 + 1;
```

I came up with the following which works well in some cases but not all:

```
playerShip.ThrustMagnitude += Timing.Scale(Timing.Instance.FR15 + 1, deltaTime);
```

The helper class in its entirety:

```
public sealed class Timing : Singleton<Timing>
{
    public static double OriginalFrameRate { get; } = 1.0d / 30.0d;
    public int FR6 { get; } = 6;
    public int FR7 { get; } = 7;
    public int FR10 { get; } = 10;
    public int FR15 { get; } = 15;
    public int FR30 { get; } = 30;
    public int FR32 { get; } = 32;
    public int FR40 { get; } = 40;
    public int FR50 { get; } = 50;
    public int FR60 { get; } = 60;

    public static int Scale(int value, double deltaTime, int? decimals = null, MidpointRounding? rounding = null)
    {
        var result = deltaTime / OriginalFrameRate * value;

        if (decimals.HasValue)
        {
            var digits = decimals.Value;

            if (rounding.HasValue)
            {
                result = Math.Round(result, digits, rounding.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                result = Math.Round(result, digits);
            }
        }
        return (int)result;
    }
}
```

The main problem I have is that it doesn't work when values are very small, yaw and roll for instance work well because they have large values, but the pitch for instance does not because its range is very small.

Say you have a value of 30 at 30 FPS, `X / 30 == 1`, but at 60 FPS it results in `X / 60 == 0`.

What approach can you suggest to tackle this problem?

Comment: You may be interested in [Calculating framerate-independent values, for linear, quadratic, and exponential functions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/185799/39518).

Comment: 1. Invent time machine, 2. Travel back in time to when the original developer made this decision, 3. tell them it's a stupid idea to use integers for positions in a game engine.

Comment: @DMGregory Looking into it, thank you.

Comment: @Philipp I used to think like so but the guys probably had a good reason to, some might certainly explain that way better than I would. Now just ask yourself, isn't it even more stupid to try to convert it to floats while it's working perfectly with ints? I used to believe in that but then realize that it might not be the brightest idea because it's way trickier than it seems.

Comment: @aybe Without access to the complete codebase I can only guess, but one possible source of bugs in such a conversion are equality checks. While checking two integers for equality can make sense, checking two floats for equality often does not, because the CPU can't tell the difference between "clearly different" and "functionally equivalent, but technically different due to a tiny rounding error". And rounding errors occur a lot with floats (see https://floating-point-gui.de).

Answer (score 1):

Your complaint is that small magnitude deltas
no longer work properly after doubling the frame rate.

There's at least two ways out.
The second seems more attractive.

1. Scale them up so they are larger magnitude, operate on the scaled values, and scale down appropriately when rendering.
2. Keep the old frame rate. That is, for a small magnitude update, skip the update unless the low order bit(s) are zero. In the case of using a 30 FPS model when rate is 60, that is just a matter of asking whether current frame number is even.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting approach which I haven't thought about, need to test it out :)

Comment: It seems that scaling by a factor of two might get you what you want. Be careful though of overflows, and some things (areas, volumes) will need to be scaled by other factors like 4 or 8. If this is done consistently, there should be no need to scale back down to render.